# Binary Tree Sort Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, object-oriented, sorting

A Binary Tree Sort is an algorithm that builds a binary search tree from the elements to be sorted, and then traverses the tree (in-order) so that the elements come out in sorted order.

Average Case Time Complexity : O(N log N) adding one element to a Binary Search Tree on average takes O(log N) time (height of a tree). Therefore, adding n elements will take O(N log N) time.

Worst Case Time Complexity : O(N^2). The worst case can be improved by using a self-balancing binary search tree, which will take O(N log N) time to sort the array in worst case.

---

Just for practicing, I've implemented the Binary Tree Sort algorithm, and if you'd like to review the code and provide any change/improvement recommendations, please do so, and I appreciate that.

---

#### Code

```
"""
This module creates a Binary Sort Tree ascendingly using In Order Tree Traverse;
Stable Sort;
Worst Case Time Complexity (For if the tree would be a chain Tree): O(N^2)
Average Case Time Complexity: O(N^Log N)
Memory Complexity: Not in place O(N)
"""

import random
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

# Not sure how to design and handle the exceptions here yet
class ExceptionHandling(Exception):
    pass


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, node_value: int) -> None:
        """
        Initializes a node with three attributes;
        `node_value` (Node Value): Must be an integer/float;
        `right_child` (Right Child): Initializes to `None`; Its value must be larger than the Root Node;
        `left_child` (Left Child): Initializes to `None`; Its value must be smaller than the Root Node;
        """
        self.node_value = node_value
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None


class BinarySearchTree(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """
        Initializes the Root Node of the Binary Tree to None;
        """
        self.root = None

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """
        Returns True if the tree doesn't have a node;
        """
        return self.root == None

    def insert(self, new_node: int) -> None:
        """
        Inserts an integer-value Node in the Tree;
        """
        self.root = self._insert(self.root, new_node)

    def _insert(self, parent: int, new_node: int) -> int:
        """
        Inserts an integer value in the left or right Node; 
        Returns the parent Node;
        """
        # If tree is empty
        if parent is None:
            parent = Node(new_node)
        # If the new Node value is smaller than its parent Node value
        elif new_node < parent.node_value:
            parent.left_child = self._insert(parent.left_child, new_node)
        # If the new Node value is bigger than its parent Node value
        else:
            parent.right_child = self._insert(parent.right_child, new_node)

        return parent

    def inorder(self) -> None:
        """
        Calls the _inorder traversing method;
        """
        self._inorder(self.root)

    def _inorder(self, parent: int) -> None:
        """
        Traverses the tree inorder (Left Node, Root Node, Right Node)
        """
        if parent is None:
            return
        self._inorder(parent.left_child)
        print(f'{parent.node_value}')
        self._inorder(parent.right_child)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tree = BinarySearchTree()

    for i in range(random.randint(20, 30)):
        tree.insert(random.uniform(-10, 10))

    tree.inorder()
```

#### Sources

- [Tree Sort - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort)
- [Tree Sort - Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-sort/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Type Hints

From these lines:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
```

it looks like you intend to add type-hints for a type `T` to you code.  But nowhere are you using `T` as a type hint.  You probably wanted to actually use `T`, such as like:

```
def __init__(self, node_value: T) -> None
```

Either that, or delete the `typing` code.

### Exception Handling

You have:

```
class ExceptionHandling(Exception):
    pass
```

but nowhere are you actually executing `raise ExceptionHandling("Your error message")`.  Moreover, nowhere do I actually see a need to raise an exception; you aren't doing anything that could fail.  Until you have a need for raising your own custom exception, you could remove this code.

### class Node(object):

Since you are using f-strings, it is clear, you are using Python 3.  In Python 3+, you don't need to inherit from `object`; it is automatically implied.

### Names & Types

```
def insert(self, new_node: int) -> None:
```

Is `new_node` a `Node` or an `int`?  The variable name suggests it would be a `Node`, but it is typed as an `int`.  When you use it, you are passing in an int.  Maybe `new_value` would be clearer?

```
def _insert(self, parent: int, new_node: int) -> int:
```

Now we're definitely confused.  Is `parent` an `int`?  Does this function return an `int`?  Both seem to be a definite "no".  Those types should be `Node`.  And again, `new_node` should be renamed, because it isn't a `Node`.

### Method naming (and docstrings)

What does `inorder` do?  I'd expect it to return the contents of the tree "in order".  But the type-hint says it returns `None`, so that is not correct.  Let's consult help:

```
>>> help(BinarySearchTree.inorder)
Help on function inorder in module __main__:

inorder(self) -> None
    Calls the _inorder traversing method;

>>>
```

Well, that's entirely unhelpful.  It calls a private `_inorder` traversing method.  Ok, but what does it do???

Name functions based on what they do.  Your `inorder` function **prints** the tree in order, so name it with `print` in its name, such as `print_inorder`.

Also, write docstrings to tell a caller what the function does.  Use a high-level description.  Include any requirements, preconditions and/or postconditions.  Do not include implementation details.  The caller cares only about what it does and how to use the function properly; they only care the function works, not how it works.

```
def print_inorder(self) -> None:
    """
    Print the tree in ascending order, one element per line, to sys.stdout
    """
    self._inorder(self.root)
```

Finally, your class is named `BinarySearchTree`, yet it provides no methods for searching.  Hmm.

### Pointless f-string

The statement:

```
print(f'{parent.node_value}')
```

is a complicated way of writing:

```
print(parent.node_value)
```

### Algorithm

Your `insert` / `_insert` functions are overly complicated.  There is no need to use recursion.  Moreover, returning the `parent` from `_insert` is mostly useless, because the caller is passing `parent` to the function; it only matters when the caller passes `None` in as the parent.

A non-recursive approach:

```
def insert(self, new_value: int) -> None:

    new_node = Node(new_value)

    if self.root:
        parent = self.root
        while True:
            if new_value < parent.node_value:
                if parent.left_child:
                    parent = parent.left_child
                else:
                    parent.left_child = new_node
                    break
            else:
                if parent.right_child:
                    parent = parent.right_child
                else:
                    parent.right_child = new_node
                    break
    else:
        self.root = new_node
```

### Possible Improvements

#### Encapsulation

`Node` is an internal detail of the `BinarySearchTree`.  You could make it an internal class:

```
class BinarySearchTree:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, node_value:T ) -> None:
            self.node_value = node_value
            self.right_child = None
            self.left_child = None

    def __init__(self) -> None
        self.root = None

    ...


       parent = BinarySearchTree.Node(new_node)

    ...
```

#### Iterator

Instead of the method `inorder` printing the contents of the tree, perhaps it could return an iterator which would traverse the tree returning elements one at a time.  The caller could then print them, or perform whatever operation they desired.

```
for value in tree.inorder():
    print(value)
```

Instead of naming this iterator creating function `inorder`, it could be named `__iter__`, in which case, the caller would just need to write:

```
for value in tree:
    print(value)
```

You'd create this iterator in one of two ways.  The "hard way", returning a new iterator object, with a `__next__` method.  Or the "easy way" using a generator function, using `yield` and `yield from` statements.

Answer (score 3):

### Exceptions

```
# Not sure how to design and handle the exceptions here yet
```

Your syntax is more or less fine, though you'll obviously want to rename the exception class. The purpose of an exception like this is to allow you to `raise` something specific to your application that consumer code might be interested in catching. One place you could potentially raise:

```
    if parent is None:
        return
```

It's unlikely that silent-fail is the right thing to do, here.

### `is None`

This:

```
return self.root == None
```

should probably be

```
return self.root is None
```

### Member types

These assignments:

```
    self.right_child = None
    self.left_child = None
```

should receive type hints, since it's not obvious what they'll eventually receive. My guess is

```
self.right_child: Node = None
self.left_child: Node = None
```

### English is not C;

You have a funny habit of terminating your comments with semicolons. That isn't necessary.

### Node value types

> `node_value` (Node Value): Must be an integer/float

So which is it - an integer, or a float? Given that your usage of this value only requires that it be comparable, I'd suggest `float`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this typevar but it seems over complicated. Why are you specifying the type and using two classes when you need only one. Here's my solution.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def add(self, val):
        if val < self.val:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = Node(val)
            else:
                self.left.add(val)
        else:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = Node(val)
            else:
                self.right.add(val)
    def sort(self):
        a = []
        b = [self.val]
        c = []
        if self.left:
            a = self.left.sort()
        if self.right:
            c = self.right.sort()
        return a+b+c
    def str(self):
        a, b = "", ""
        if self.left:
            a = self.left.str()
        if self.right:
            b = self.right.str()
        return "({}, {}, {})".format(self.val, a, b)
def tree_sort(s):
    node = Node(s[0])
    for val in s[1:]:
        node.add(val)
    return node.sort()

l=[123, 48, 23, 100, 56,2, 10, 273, 108, 398, 100, 2651, 12]
print(tree_sort(l))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your answer does focus on an alternative implementation, while answers should preferably focus on a review of the code/approach provided. There are many binary-sort questions on Code Review, what makes your answer specific to this question?